# Datetime updating realtime, no other elements shown

Tags: python, datetime, pyqt

Im starting on an app that will show the current datetime.datetime.now() along with a button that can add the current time to a list when pressed. datetime is updating itself every second, but I cant see the button element in the window at all.

I'm pretty new to pyqt so I'm sure that there is something wrong here.

Is there anyone here that can help me figure out why I cant see any other elements than the updating datetime? is it overwriting it or something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from datetime import datetime


class feedingTime(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.label = QLabel(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),self)
        self.button = QPushButton("test")
        layout.addWidget(self.label,0,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.button,0,1)


        self.timer = QTimer(self.label)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.displayTime)
        self.timer.start()

    def displayTime(self):
        self.label.setText(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = feedingTime()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set your layout :)

```
...
layout.addWidget(self.label,0,0)
layout.addWidget(self.button,0,1)
self.setLayout(layout)
```

Comment: Thank you! Was pulling my hair out for one second. Cant believe I missed that part. :)